# SSRS histogram adding extra data. (chart)

Tags: reporting-services, statistics, histogram, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create a histogram to show frequency distribution using the following data in a table.

> Values 25 35 37 37 38 38 40 40 41 44 46

For some reason an extra value of 45 is being added to my chart.

I have stripped this down to my query being something like this and have placed my dataset into a table to see the data and the correct data is being pulled.

```
SELECT values FROM table
```

[image]

So my problem is that I have 11 pieces of data but 12 are being displayed. What may be missing here?

Comment: Just to eliminate the dataset, can you manually create the dataset using something like `CREATE TABLE #t (v int)` `INSERT INTO #t VALUES (25),(35),(37),(37),(38),(38),(40),(40),(41),(44),(46)`  `SELECT * FROM #t` and see if you get the same result.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, so I tried this but got the same result. So this enforces my thought that it is not the data.

Comment: Can you post the exact dataset query  and put a copy of the RDL somewhere. I can''t reproduce this.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, I started a new report locally just to see if I could recreate the problem and got the exact same problem. I used the query you gave me here to populate my dataset and put my RDL file on google drive.

[RDL File Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwnIxZ2zM58zQ2plVEIwMGM5OXc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't using the histogram properties of the series but it should give you what you want.

I created a test dataset as follows

```
CREATE TABLE #t (score int) 
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (25),(35),(37),(37),(38),(38),(40),(40),(41),(44),(46)
SELECT score, count(*) as Freq 
    FROM #t 
    GROUP BY Score
```

The obvious change is the frequency is calculated in the dataset query this time.

I then added a normal column chart, set the category groups to group on `score` and the values as `[Sum(Freq)]`

I then changed the Horizontal Axis properties as follows:
Axis Type = `Scalar (Numbers/Dates)`
Axis Range Interval = `1`

Here's a link to the RDL, it contains your version and this new version. I've not added data labels etc. but hopefully it'll be helpful.

[Histogram RDL](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7HPDPorNYQSNGJ2cVJLY09hVm8)